# Valves and plumbing size

Tags: gas, valves, liquid

I'm building a liquid rocket engine and we're using kerosene and oxygen as our propellent. Now my question is what pipe size should we use? My flow rate for kerosene is 0.160 Liters per second and we are planning to use a butterfly valve of 1.5 inch and for oxygen our flow rate is 12 L per second and we don't know which valve we should use for that.Also I want to throttle the propellents. I will be able to design the structure so that wouldn't be any problem

Comment: Please don't add additional requirements in the comments. [Edit] the question and put all the information in there.

Comment: Provide a basic P&ID sketch, include any fuel pumps or tank pressures.

Comment: Butterfly valves always leak; They are used for low pressure gasses.

Comment: @blacksmith37 That's okay once you have ignition. The system is sealed with other valves until seconds before ignition  - https://www.space-propulsion.com/spacecraft-propulsion/valves/pyrotechnic-valve.html

Comment: Idiots Guide to rocket fuels - https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/tr/pdf/AD0870258.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When designing with fluids (oil in pipes), we had some basic parameters to begin with:

return speed <= 0.5m/s

Supply speed 1.5 <> 7 m/s

However, the higher end creates more noise... so for certain environments / conditions that is not good.

You can evaluate your situation - higher speed = more losses and as you have flow rates you can work out some diameters of pipe. Once you have those then you can consider using common sizes - material choice etc

Comment: in a rocket one crucial parameter is supply speed > flame propagation speed!

Comment: @mart hopefully the OP would realise that.

Comment: The Oxidizer and Fuel are mixed at the last possible instant (inside the combustion chamber). So, the flame should not be able to propagate well into either pipeline since either oxidizer or fuel will be missing in each line ??? Assuming that the injectors are designed correctly.

Comment: I don't know where fuel and oxidiser are mixed (because OP didn't provide a sketch) and I don't anything about the injectors. I'm normally fine with assuming competence, but with things that can go boom I try to be careful

Comment: I read 'rocket' and assumed presence of some associated hardware. You are right to caution.